# RIP Margot Kidder, Superman Actress

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Margot Kidder, whose most famous role was Lois Lane in the Christopher Reeve series of Superman movies, has died at the age of 69.

[image]

In addition to her on-screen work she was also famous for her voiceovers, providing the voice for Gaia in 'Captain Planet and the Planeteers' and Rebecca Madison in 'Phantom 2040'.

Comment: ;( this makes me have sad face

Comment: Kidder also appeared in Brian DePalma's "Sisters." That film included split-screen images.

Answer (score 2):

I remember her from Quackser Fortune Has a Cousin in the Bronx (with Gene Wilder who I am sure we all miss). Her sad end I take as a warning -- we must all be careful -- we are all one serious illness away from dire straits no matter how successful or beautiful or talented we are.